# Why JavaScript trackers use img tags and not XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm trying to build a javascript analytics tracker like google analytics. I tried to look into the source of some other implementation and they use an `img` or a `script` tag to call the API backend for tracking.

I was wondering why they won't use the `XMLHttpRequest` to make the request? My guess is to avoid blocking by anti-trackers but not sure.

Anyone knows about it?

Comment: Isn't it because it's easier for everyone?

Comment: Images are harder to block

Comment: It works with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev that's true for an email like case. Here the img tag is added via the JavaScript.

Comment: @Liam any links please?

Comment: You also can share cookies with multiple domains using the images or iframes. Having the user identification cookies in the backend. Also the images are much harder to detect and block by plugins than a XHR. I've read that with js disabled it works.. it won't if you're collecting the data dynamically and putting it into the image source, but you can add manually an image into noscript tags which says to the backend that the user has disabled js, and the backend still would recognize the user.

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons:

- **Legacy**: eg Google Analytics was formerly [Urchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urchin_(software)) created back when "pixel" tracking was the de-facto standard for frontend analytics
- **Browser compatibility**: `<img>` and `<script>` implementation is identical across them all (just add the tag), which wasn't the case for `XMLHttpRequest` with older browsers.
- **Ease of implementation**: just add the `<img>` and `<script>` and it works, with `XMLHttpRequest` you actually need to write some code
- **Robustness / Prevent blocking**: `<img>` are harder to detect as being advertising/tracking related, since loading an image from another domain with a complex looking URL is actually common practice (eg think CDN)
- **Web/Email cross platform**: you can implement tracking of emails with `<img>`, you can't with `<script>` (blocked for security reasons).
- **JavaScript support**: with JS disabled, pixel tracking still works